# Angular router undefined

Tags: angular

I am getting following two errors.

1) router-outlet is not a known element for following code

```
import {Routes, RouterModule}from "@angular/router"


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: `
    <top-menu></top-menu>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  `
})
```

2) Unexpected closing tag `<a>` for following code

```
import {Routes, RouterModule} from "@angular/router"

@Component({
  selector: 'top-menu',
  template: `    
    <a [routerLink]=['new']> New </a>
      <a [routerLink]=['list']> List </a>
  `
})
```

The routes are defined as follows:

```
export const routes:Routes = [
  {path:'new', component:MyParaComponent},
  {path:'list', component:MyListComponent}
];

export const appRouterModule =RouterModule.forRoot(routes);
```

Interestingly, if I add appRouterModule in imports in app.module.ts then I get an error that app.routes.ts (the file where appRouterModule) is defined doesn't export any module.

`.../app/app.routes"' has no exported member 'appRouterModule'.`

Comment: What does your `@NgModule`'s look like?

Comment: Following is the link to cut-down version in Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/hLME9NSoXeSuLp7MxtGw?p=preview

Comment: For simplicity "<a routerLink='new'>New</a>" can be used, if you are not passing any fragment, or dynamic id etc.

Comment: I originally tried without double quotes but it didnt work either

Comment: plunker needs two changes, "FormsModule" import is missing. And "appRouterModule" should be in imports not in declarations, also AppModule has import two times. After this all worked.

Comment: Here is updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UyWL0CAgDU0MSbEQUqD2?p=preview

Comment: @Malik is correct. Manu - Have a look at the official routing guide https://angular.io/guide/router - there is a useful live example on the page, in addition to plenty of info how to use Angular Routing

Comment: Thanks. Working now.

Answer (score 1):

*Corrected*

Part 1:
You need to import `RouterOutlet` from "@angular/router", and instead of importing RouterModule into your component, you should import it into your the parent Module (if you arent already).

Part 2:

`<a [routerLink]=['new']> New </a>` should be
`<a [routerLink]="['new']"> New </a>`

Comment: Following is the link to cut-down version in Plunker - https://plnkr.co/edit/hLME9NSoXeSuLp7MxtGw?p=preview